# Design pattern for multiple messaging systems in a cloud environment

Tags: design-patterns, rabbitmq, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I am working on designing a messaging system in Amazon web services cloud environment. We can use either SQS or any other AMQP systems like RabbitMQ. The decision can be made later, but the design should be robust enough to support any underlying messaging system later.The decision on the underlying system would be taken later based on the pros and cons of each, which is not of a major concern as of now.

Since it should be Producer/Consumer model, I zeroed in on Strategy pattern for the client/producer of messages which will use Spring beans to inject the right strategy implementation based on chosen system. My question is, are there any other pattern which suits this case, may be an Adapter. Why or why not or is Strategy the best pattern for this case?

Thanks for any inputs!!

-Tatha

Comment: Hard to say. Have you explored easynetq or other frameworks that support the common cases (producer/consumer, publish/subscribe, request/response)? This can give you a good idea for decisions

Comment: Thanks will look into other frameworks

Comment: We need more details. Many patterns are solutions to problems of supporting variability in a clean way, but with a cost to complexity, number of modules, etc. What are the APIs like for the different messaging systems? Adapter may be sufficient if the messaging systems' APIs are simple. How many future systems do you want to support? If the chances are high there'll be more than two, then a pattern could be worth it. If it's only two, and it's just simple messaging, how ugly would conditional code be? Don't forget If you go with Strategy/Adapter, you'll need a simple factory or DI.

Comment: Thanks @Fuhrmanator for your inputs. I don't think there will be more than two underlying messaging systems. Since we use Spring, the strategy with simple factory can be implemented by it. We might also do away with multiple queue systems and implement the requirement via Spring integration

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a very conceptual question, I suggest made some general U.M.L. diagram ( class and sequence, primary ) that describe / model each messaging system.

Altought, U.M.L. is not the subject of the question, it helps a lot when implementing a Software Design Pattern into a real world application.

Check for common features in the given models.

The common or similar attributes or properties , will suggest maybe a pattern like the `Adapter`, or even the `Decorator`  .

The common or similar operations , will suggest maybe a pattern like the `Adapter`, and, of course the `Strategy`  .

It seems, that you may have some application that is the `Consumer`, and other that is the `Producer`, and maybe both.

It seems, that it may be more like either `Adapter` or `Decorator`,
and maybe the `Strategy` as a secondary complement pattern.

In the `Consumer` code, you may have to apply the `Adapter`, instead of directly using an specific messaging system.

The same applies for the `Producer`.